# Python: multiply rows in column and integrate it

Tags: python, math, graph, statistics

I have two csv-files (data1 and data2) in folder "in". Files incude two columns with data. First column is wavelength and second intensity. The start and end wavelength is diferent, and delta wavelength is diferen, too. I need the multiply this two data where wavelength is intersects. After integrate data by wavelength for example from 300 to 800 nm if data include in this region if not that start and end which include.
Here is the graphic with data1 and data2 and result of multiply this data.
[image]

**data1 example:**

```
Wavelength (nm),Intensity (a. u.)
339.745,0
340.13,0
340.515,0
340.899,0
341.284,0
341.669,0
342.053,0
342.437,0
342.822,0
343.206,0
343.591,0
343.975,0
344.359,0
344.743,0
345.128,0
345.512,0
345.896,0
346.28,0
346.664,0
347.048,0
347.432,0
347.816,0
348.199,0
348.583,0
348.967,0
349.351,0
349.734,0
350.118,-0.07
350.502,-0.06
350.885,0.06
351.269,-0.09
351.652,-0.02
352.036,-0.07
352.419,-0.07
352.802,0.03
353.186,-0.03
353.569,-0.03
353.952,0
354.335,0
354.718,0.03
355.101,0.06
355.484,-0.05
355.867,-0.02
356.25,-0.01
356.633,-0.03
357.016,-0.05
357.399,-0.05
357.782,0.03
358.165,0.09
358.547,0
358.93,-0.01
359.313,0.07
359.695,0.01
360.078,0.02
360.46,-0.06
360.843,0
361.225,-0.04
361.608,-0.02
361.99,0
362.372,0.02
362.754,-0.01
363.137,-0.02
363.519,-0.02
363.901,-0.01
364.283,0
364.665,-0.05
365.047,0.01
365.429,-0.04
365.811,-0.01
366.193,-0.03
366.575,0.05
366.956,0.01
367.338,-0.01
367.72,0.03
368.101,-0.02
368.483,-0.04
368.865,-0.04
369.246,-0.04
369.628,-0.06
370.009,-0.07
370.391,-0.01
370.772,-0.06
371.153,-0.01
371.534,-0.07
371.916,0
372.297,-0.01
372.678,0.04
373.059,-0.02
373.44,0
373.821,0.03
374.202,-0.03
374.583,0
374.964,-0.05
375.345,0.03
375.726,0.03
376.107,0
376.487,0.05
376.868,-0.04
377.249,0.03
377.629,-0.06
378.01,0.08
378.39,0.05
378.771,-0.01
379.151,0.04
379.532,-0.03
379.912,-0.01
380.292,0.01
380.672,-0.01
381.053,0
381.433,-0.06
381.813,0
382.193,-0.04
382.573,0
382.953,0.01
383.333,-0.02
383.713,0.01
384.093,-0.07
384.473,-0.03
384.852,0.04
385.232,0
385.612,-0.03
385.992,0.02
386.371,-0.03
386.751,-0.01
387.13,-0.05
387.51,0.01
387.889,-0.04
388.269,0.03
388.648,-0.05
389.027,0.04
389.407,0
389.786,-0.02
390.165,-0.02
390.544,0.04
390.923,0.01
391.302,-0.01
391.681,-0.02
392.06,-0.04
392.439,0
392.818,0
393.197,0.01
393.576,0
393.955,-0.01
394.333,-0.02
394.712,-0.02
395.091,0.01
395.469,0.02
395.848,-0.04
396.226,0
396.605,-0.01
396.983,0.02
397.362,-0.01
397.74,0.05
398.118,0.01
398.496,0.02
398.875,-0.01
399.253,0
399.631,-0.04
400.009,0.01
400.387,0
400.765,0
401.143,0.01
401.521,0.01
401.899,-0.03
402.276,-0.03
402.654,-0.03
403.032,0.01
403.41,-0.04
403.787,-0.03
404.165,0.01
404.542,-0.04
404.92,0.01
405.297,-0.01
405.675,0.02
406.052,0
406.43,0.02
406.807,-0.03
407.184,0.02
407.561,0
407.939,-0.02
408.316,0
408.693,-0.02
409.07,0.02
409.447,0
409.824,0.01
410.201,0.02
410.577,0
410.954,-0.02
411.331,0
411.708,0
412.084,-0.01
412.461,-0.02
412.838,-0.01
413.214,-0.03
413.591,0.01
413.967,-0.02
414.344,-0.02
414.72,0
415.096,-0.01
415.473,0.01
415.849,-0.01
416.225,0.01
416.601,0.02
416.977,0.03
417.354,0.03
417.73,0
418.106,0.03
418.481,-0.01
418.857,0
419.233,0
419.609,0.01
419.985,-0.01
420.361,-0.02
420.736,-0.04
421.112,-0.03
421.487,0.02
421.863,-0.02
422.239,0.01
422.614,-0.01
422.989,-0.03
423.365,-0.02
423.74,-0.02
424.115,-0.01
424.491,-0.01
424.866,0.04
425.241,0.01
425.616,-0.01
425.991,-0.01
426.366,0.02
426.741,0.01
427.116,-0.02
427.491,0
427.866,-0.02
428.241,-0.01
428.616,-0.02
428.99,-0.03
429.365,0.02
429.74,0.02
430.114,-0.02
430.489,0
430.863,-0.01
431.238,-0.01
431.612,0.01
431.986,0
432.361,-0.01
432.735,-0.03
433.109,-0.03
433.483,-0.02
433.858,0.01
434.232,0.01
434.606,0
434.98,0.03
435.354,-0.02
435.728,-0.02
436.102,0
436.475,0.02
436.849,-0.02
437.223,0.01
437.597,0.02
437.97,0.02
438.344,-0.02
438.717,-0.02
439.091,0.03
439.464,0
439.838,0.03
440.211,-0.02
440.585,-0.02
440.958,0
441.331,0.02
441.704,-0.01
442.078,-0.02
442.451,-0.03
442.824,0.02
443.197,-0.01
443.57,0
443.943,0.01
444.316,0.01
444.689,0.02
445.061,-0.02
445.434,0
445.807,0
446.18,0
446.552,0.01
446.925,-0.02
447.297,0.03
447.67,0
448.042,-0.01
448.415,0
448.787,-0.02
449.159,0
449.532,-0.01
449.904,-0.01
450.276,0.02
450.648,-0.01
451.02,-0.03
451.392,-0.01
451.764,-0.02
452.136,0.01
452.508,0
452.88,-0.01
453.252,0.02
453.624,0.02
453.996,-0.01
454.367,0.02
454.739,-0.01
455.111,-0.03
455.482,0
455.854,0
456.225,-0.01
456.597,-0.02
456.968,-0.01
457.339,-0.02
457.711,0
458.082,0.02
458.453,-0.02
458.824,-0.01
459.195,0
459.566,0
459.937,0.01
460.308,0.01
460.679,0
461.05,0.01
461.421,-0.02
461.792,-0.01
462.163,0.01
462.533,0
462.904,-0.01
463.275,-0.01
463.645,0.02
464.016,-0.01
464.386,0.03
464.757,0
465.127,0
465.498,0
465.868,-0.01
466.238,0.01
466.608,0
466.979,0
467.349,0.01
467.719,0.01
468.089,0.02
468.459,0
468.829,0
469.199,0.01
469.568,-0.01
469.938,0.01
470.308,0.02
470.678,0.02
471.047,0.02
471.417,0.01
471.787,-0.01
472.156,0
472.526,0.01
472.895,0.02
473.265,0.02
473.634,0.02
474.003,0.01
474.373,0.01
474.742,0
475.111,0.01
475.48,0.03
475.849,0.03
476.218,0.01
476.587,0
476.956,0
477.325,0.01
477.694,0.02
478.063,0.02
478.432,0.02
478.8,0.01
479.169,0.02
479.538,0.02
479.906,0.02
480.275,0.01
480.643,0.04
481.012,0.02
481.38,0.01
481.748,0.02
482.117,0.02
482.485,0.04
482.853,0.02
483.221,0.04
483.59,0.05
483.958,0.04
484.326,0.04
484.694,0.04
485.062,0.03
485.43,0.05
485.797,0.05
486.165,0.05
486.533,0.07
486.901,0.07
487.268,0.07
487.636,0.05
488.004,0.08
488.371,0.09
488.739,0.08
489.106,0.09
489.473,0.09
489.841,0.1
490.208,0.09
490.575,0.11
490.943,0.12
491.31,0.12
491.677,0.12
492.044,0.12
492.411,0.15
492.778,0.16
493.145,0.16
493.512,0.17
493.879,0.17
494.246,0.19
494.612,0.21
494.979,0.21
495.346,0.22
495.712,0.24
496.079,0.24
496.445,0.27
496.812,0.26
497.178,0.28
497.545,0.31
497.911,0.31
498.277,0.34
498.644,0.35
499.01,0.36
499.376,0.39
499.742,0.4
500.108,0.43
500.474,0.44
500.84,0.45
501.206,0.48
501.572,0.5
501.938,0.53
502.304,0.54
502.669,0.57
503.035,0.59
503.401,0.62
503.766,0.65
504.132,0.68
504.497,0.69
504.863,0.74
505.228,0.79
505.594,0.77
505.959,0.86
506.324,0.87
506.69,0.91
507.055,0.93
507.42,0.96
507.785,0.99
508.15,1.04
508.515,1.06
508.88,1.11
509.245,1.14
509.61,1.2
509.975,1.21
510.339,1.27
510.704,1.3
511.069,1.36
511.434,1.38
511.798,1.44
512.163,1.48
512.527,1.51
512.892,1.55
513.256,1.6
513.62,1.65
513.985,1.7
514.349,1.75
514.713,1.8
515.077,1.85
515.441,1.89
515.806,1.94
516.17,1.99
516.534,2.03
516.897,2.11
517.261,2.11
517.625,2.19
517.989,2.25
518.353,2.29
518.716,2.36
519.08,2.38
519.444,2.42
519.807,2.48
520.171,2.54
520.534,2.57
520.898,2.63
521.261,2.68
521.624,2.73
521.988,2.75
522.351,2.8
522.714,2.9
523.077,2.92
523.44,2.96
523.803,2.99
524.166,3.06
524.529,3.07
524.892,3.13
525.255,3.17
525.618,3.22
525.981,3.28
526.344,3.31
526.706,3.35
527.069,3.38
527.431,3.39
527.794,3.44
528.156,3.48
528.519,3.5
528.881,3.57
529.244,3.59
529.606,3.61
529.968,3.65
530.33,3.67
530.693,3.7
531.055,3.71
531.417,3.76
```

**data2 example:**

```
Wavelength (nm),Intensity (a. u.)
380,2.00E-04
385,3.96E-04
390,8.00E-04
395,1.55E-03
400,2.80E-03
405,4.66E-03
410,7.40E-03
415,1.18E-02
420,1.75E-02
425,2.27E-02
430,2.73E-02
435,3.26E-02
440,3.79E-02
445,4.24E-02
450,4.68E-02
455,5.21E-02
460,6.00E-02
465,7.29E-02
470,9.10E-02
475,1.13E-01
480,1.39E-01
485,1.70E-01
490,2.08E-01
495,2.58E-01
500,3.23E-01
505,4.05E-01
510,5.03E-01
515,6.08E-01
520,7.10E-01
525,7.95E-01
530,8.62E-01
535,9.15E-01
540,9.54E-01
545,9.80E-01
550,9.95E-01
555,1.00E+00
560,9.95E-01
565,9.79E-01
570,9.52E-01
575,9.16E-01
580,8.70E-01
585,8.16E-01
590,7.57E-01
595,6.95E-01
600,6.31E-01
605,5.67E-01
610,5.03E-01
615,4.42E-01
620,3.81E-01
625,3.21E-01
630,2.65E-01
635,2.17E-01
640,1.75E-01
645,1.38E-01
650,1.07E-01
655,8.17E-02
660,6.10E-02
665,4.43E-02
670,3.20E-02
675,2.35E-02
680,1.70E-02
685,1.19E-02
690,8.21E-03
695,5.77E-03
700,4.10E-03
705,2.93E-03
710,2.09E-03
715,1.48E-03
720,1.05E-03
725,7.40E-04
730,5.20E-04
735,3.61E-04
740,2.49E-04
745,1.72E-04
750,1.20E-04
755,8.46E-05
760,6.00E-05
765,4.24E-05
770,3.00E-05
775,2.12E-05
780,1.50E-05
785,1.06E-05
790,7.47E-06
795,5.26E-06
800,3.70E-06
805,2.61E-06
810,1.84E-06
815,1.30E-06
820,9.11E-07
825,6.36E-07
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I add 2 files example. I need myltiply them and find integra for example: integral = from 300 nm to 800 nm (data1 * data2) by wavelenghth.

Comment: You should try using pandas

Comment: Yes, I know it. Thank you very much)) I can multiply data, but I need multiply with condition, because the delta of wavelength is different. Can you show me how I can do it?